# Importing core.swc and flex.swc in a Flash project

Tags: flash

I want to use Starling in Flash Professional: they told me I must import core.swc and flex.swc in my Flash project. How do I find these two? And how do I import them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They come with Flex SDK. Inside the SDK they are in the frameworks/libs/ directory or somewhere around that place it fluctuated from version to version.

You can download older version of SDK from here: http://sourceforge.net/adobe/flexsdk/wiki/Download%20Flex%204.5/

And the newer ones from here: http://incubator.apache.org/flex/download.html

Note that from the user perspective Apache Flex distribution is more convoluted (due to licensing issues) and to have a fully functional SDK you might prefer to use SDK installer (that's not part of the official distribution, but was created by some enthusiastic contributor): http://incubator.apache.org/flex/installer.html

Comment: It seems there's a core.swc, but no flex.swc (I installed with the installer)